Am I building the Grand Piano correctly?
I am in this step of 21323 Grand Piano. Unless I lift the gray bar above, it prevents the axle from rotating counter-clockwise. I have to lift it for the axle to rotate. Will there be a step later on which will lift the grey bar? I do not know how to change directions in the Powered Up app.

Is my gear correctly installed?


A later step in what?

@Henriksupportsthecommunity Possibly related: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/16298/grand-piano-page-269-of-instructions-are-the-gears-suppose-to-stop-after-a-qua

The linked question shows the correct construction, which seems identical to these photos. The function of the grey latch preventing counter-clockwise rotation is also explained there.
